# Programatically free application occupied space from my application due to "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget"

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, bitmap, out-of-memory

this question is not a repeat. I am capturing many images during different part of my application through camera.

While calling onActivityResult, I compressed the bitmap with this method:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = Const.SampleSize;
options.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free
                                    // memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
options.inScaled = true;
```

In my application, I need to put a timestamp on this image, which consumes a lot of application memory. For this I also compress this image after writing on that with following method:

```
Bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos);
```

But still I am getting crash after some screens with:

```
3686400-byte external allocation too large for this process.
VM won't let us allocate 3686400 bytes
```

I can see the memory allocation at any stage with this method:

        `protected static void displayMemoryUsage(String message) {
        int usedKBytes = (int) (Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1024L);
        String usedMegsString = String.format("%s - usedMemory = Memory Used: %d KB", message, usedKBytes);
        Log.d("Memoery Count", usedMegsString);
    }`

And from this i can see that it crashes after Application memory reaches approx. 24MB.

***So my question is that is there any method to free memory of Application ?***

P.S.: I have tried following things already:

1. System.runFinalization();
2. System.gc();
3. *Bitmap.recycle();* for recycling Bitmaps
4. *WeakReference* for storing Bitmaps
5. android:largeHeap="true" in Manifest file

Please suggest me any method through which I can free heavy load of memory from my Application. i know that it restricts me due to limited Application allocation space. But is there any work around for that as I can't compress more that a particular limit.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I want to code or a reference on how to free application occupied space just like Clean Master, but only for my particular app while its running. Hope that makes sense !

Comment: Please comment here before down voting the question. Its a genuine question, with all the possibilities explored before questioning at SO.